# Missing Bytes in Client Server application in C

Tags: c, client-server

I have created a Client/Server application in C by using the SSL library. the issue i am facing is each time i send a file there are some bytes missing in the start of file.

let suppose the text file which i am sending contains

```
123456789
```

and when the client receive the file it would contains

```
56789
```

**Server-Code**

```
void sendFile(SSL* ssl)
{
    char response[2048] = {0};
    int read = 0;
    FILE* fd;

    fd = fopen("snt.txt","rb");

    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        printf("file loading failed\n");
        return;
    }
    while ((read=fread(response,sizeof(char),1024,fd)) > 0)
    {
        SSL_write(ssl,response,read);
        printf("read :%d\n",read);
        //puts(response);
        //printf("***Data Sent***\n");
        memset(response,0,1024);
    }
    printf("***Data Sent***\n");
    fclose(fd);
}
```

**Client Code**

```
FILE *ft;
char filebuf[2048];
int read = 0;
int error_check=0;
ft = fopen("rcv.txt","ab");
if (ft == NULL)
{
    printf("Can not open file to write\n");
    return -1;
}
memset(filebuf,0,2048);
int cnk=1;
while ((error_check=BIO_read(bio,&read,sizeof(int)))>0)
{
    //printf("%d read\n",read);
    if (error_check==0)
        break;

    if (read==0)
        break;

    BIO_read(bio,filebuf,read);
    printf("%d Chunk Recieved\n",cnk++);
    //puts(filebuf);
    fwrite(filebuf,sizeof(char),strlen(filebuf),ft);
    memset(filebuf,0,2048);

}
printf("***File Recieved***");
fclose(ft);
```

the other issue is client side is not terminated, control doesn't get away from the while-loop, kindly guide me how can i tackle these issues

Comment: FILEBUF is contant having value 1024, i have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `size(int)` is `4`, I'd say the 1<sup>st</sup> 4 bytes are read by this line:

```
while ((error_check=BIO_read(bio,&read,sizeof(int)))>0)
```

That leaves the rest of the data sent to this line:

```
BIO_read(bio,filebuf,read);
```

The latter reads it into `filebuf` which then is written to the file `rcv.txt`.

Comment: In other words, the server code isn't sending the length prefix the client code is expecting before the data.

Comment: @WiXXeY: As *WhozCraig* mentions the server and the client do not use ("speak") the same protocol. The client expects the server to send the amount of data to be transfered in the first place. The server is missing to do so.